# How can I fetch the url only from an array object

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression, jayway

I'm trying to modify this JSON to remove key values except "url" from an array object of attachment.

Json Path version I'm using: 2.7.0

```json
{
  "fields": {
      "item_name": "mypass\n",
      "id": "nopass cell",
      "Attachment": [
          {
              "id": "attaMKW4RR5misdsD",
              "url": "https://url1.com",
              "filename": "test-nopass.txt",
              "size": 17,
              "type": "text/plain"
          },
          {
              "id": "attHy3s6MBzce7Qoq",
              "url": "https://url2.com",
              "filename": "test-mypass.txt",
              "size": 28,
              "type": "text/plain"
          },
          {
              "id": "atth4oFqzanlk9532",
              "url": "https://url3.com",
              "filename": "test- yourpass .txt",
              "size": 28,
              "type": "text/plain"
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

here I want to modify this json object to the below code.

```json
{
  "fields": {
      "item_name": "mypass\n",
      "id": "nopass cell",
      "Attachment": [
          {
              "url": "https://url1.com",
          },
          {
              "url": "https://url2.com",
          },
          {
              "url": "https://url3.com",
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

so how can I achieve this from Jayway JsonPath expression?

Comment: So over here you want just url in attachments right?

Comment: yes. so the object will be item_name, id, Attachment (with objects contains only url )

Comment: So after fetching data not possible to modify this response according to our need via looping or map functions?

Comment: we can modify the json

Comment: JSONPath is not solution for what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it can be achieved using JsonPath. However, this can be achieved using **Jackson**.

**First, add the following dependency in your pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Then you may try the below code. It should work**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
...
public static void removeFieldsFromJson(String json) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
        JsonNode fields = jsonNode.get("fields");
        JsonNode attachments = fields.get("Attachment");
        
        for (JsonNode attachment : attachments) {
            ((ObjectNode) attachment).remove("id");
            ((ObjectNode) attachment).remove("filename");
            ((ObjectNode) attachment).remove("size");
            ((ObjectNode) attachment).remove("type");
        }
        
        objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File("C:\\test\\payload.json"), jsonNode);
    }
```